# django postgres integration error, no such table - auth user

Tags: django, postgresql, digital-ocean

After updating the django settings.py default database to correct values.
i am able to run makemigrations and migrate command and also create super user. but when i login to the admin it gives me error of “no such table - auth user, OPERATIONAL ERROR”.

I noticed that even if i delete db.sqlite3 file, it comes back when i try to login, i think django looks for table in db.sqlite3 and not postgres.

why db.sqlite3 file re appear after deleting ?
how do i correctly configure my settings.py ?

i am integration using digitalocean managed database services with django installed in one droplet, i have integrated both preciously without error but i installed postgres, this is the first time using managed database service.

Thanks

Comment: Try migrateng with your app name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your django settings are still pointing to the SQlite database.

Did you reload your WSGI process ? If not, the old SQlite settings are still used in memory.

Comment: i will check reloading the wsgi processor and update you.